# Aadhar Authentication using otp in nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am in need to use AADHAR API. Basically, I am developing my 1st NodeJs project for  health care and in that, i am doing patient registration. Now here I want to do simple AADHAR authentication using OTP request wherein the patient will enter his/her AADHAR number and in return gets an OTP which is submitted to AADHAR Auth API and once authentication is successful we will fetch eKYC details of a patient and use them in my project

https://uidai.gov.in/images/resource/Aadhaar_Authentication_API-2.5_Revision-1_of_January_2022.pdf

I have gone through the above document. But as a beginner I didnt understood this. Anybody please help me on this.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a tutorial where someone instructs you. Please share the code you've attempted so that others can better understand your issue or attempt to replicate it.